# Regex match is throwing stackoverflow in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have long string for which my regex is failing. For short string like 10 times shorter it is working fine but for long string stack over flow occurs.

My pattern

```
static String shot = "\\["
            + "("
                    + "<"
                    + "[0-9a-fA-F]*"
                    + ">"
            + ")*"
        + "\\]";
```

string :

```
static String s = "[<FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><0020><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><0026><FFFD><0028><0029><002A><FFFD><002C><002D><002E><002F><0030><0031><0032><0033><0034><0035><0036><0037><0038><0039><003A><FFFD><003C><FFFD><003E><FFFD><FFFD><0041><0042><0043><0044><0045><FFFD><0047><0048><0049><004A><004B><004C><004D><004E><004F><0050><0051><0052><0053><0054><0055><FFFD><0057><FFFD><0059><FFFD><FFFD><005C><FFFD><FFFD><005F><FFFD><0061><0062><0063><0064><0065><0066><0067><0068><0069><006A><006B><006C><006D><006E><006F><0070><0071><0072><0073><0074><0075><0076><0077><0078><0079><007A><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><201C><201D><FFFD><2019><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><FFFD>]";
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror

Comment: The problem is that the regex engine still backtracks a lot here. You should think of using possessive quantifiers, use [`String regex = "\\[(<[0-9a-fA-F]*>)*+]";`](http://rextester.com/SLV51009).

Comment: I have tried to use *? insted of * and also tried useing {0,10} after >